# Customize OEM Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, clone, oem

Scenario:

Using OEM Recovery Discs from HP, I do a fresh install of windows 7. Windows 7 gets activated by the BIOS in these HP machines. If I clone the images from the base machine. Would windows get activate if I image other HP computers with base this image?

Reason I would like to do this, we need 3 OEM discs to installs windows 7. After that, there is still bloat ware that needs to be uninstall. Would this be possible?

Comment: Only thing I can think if is to try and find out!

Comment: My bet is it will work fine, never tried it on any of my HP laptops but can not think of any reason it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the OEM image wouldn't be specific to your machine if they came from HP. Your other option would be to use a VL install disk and slipstream it. The activation should work so long as the versions match up, plus you can put all the updates/needed drivers into the image.

It really boils down to legality.

This link is to a page that covers the legal issues of imaging.

http://www.aidanfinn.com/2013/05/tip-legally-deploying-images-windows-to-oem-licensed-pcs/

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform the cloning, be sure to run sysprep on the base machine to avoid conflicts with computernames and such.